# Open an HTML file in Adobe Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm a very unexperienced programmer.  I've been doing codeacademy javascript track but I found out that you need to put javascript in an HTML file?  I want to make sure that I can write basic javascript before continuing on code academy so I downloaded brackets and when I tried to test my program with the live preview feature it said, "Open an HTML file or make sure there is an index.html file in your project in order to launch live preview.  I typed this up very quickly so there are probably plenty errors but here is the code if that helps answer my question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Daily Programmer Challenge 12/15/14 </h1>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var volume = prompt ("Enter the volume of the container that you wish to make");

var cube = math.pow(volume, 1/3);

window.document.write("The size of the container is '+cube+' width, '+cube+' high, and '+cube+' tall");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can also put javascript in another separate file. like test.js

Comment: Try using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to test your JavaScript first.

Comment: @RyanJ: I was going to propose him to use jsfiddle too, but document.write is disabled on it.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate... there's also a problem with your string concat. You're using the `+` operator to concat a value enclosed in `''`, but you don't close the `"` first, so you'll end up printing the `+cube+` literally. Change it to `...is '" + cube + "' ...`

Comment: once file is saved can open in any browser also. browsers have built in debugging tools for javascript (F12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save this code that you pasted as a file called index.html and then try Bracket's live preview.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone, this problem can be resolved by following steps:-

1. On menu bar, go to  File --> Open Folder (folder which have your html file for live preview)
2. Select Folder
3. Select your html file from left side bar for live preview
4. Click on bolt icon on right (preview button)

All it melts down to the fact, that you need that folder(which have your file) selected to view your output in live preview. 
Let me know, if it helps someone. :)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]